# xrandr cannot use rotation "normal" reflection "none"

Tags: manjaro, xrandr

I'm running Manjaro, when booting up the display is at the wrong resolution (I don't know what resolution it is at, but its square on a rectangular screen). This is the same at the log in screen and once logged in.

I've tried to alter it using arandr but that gives me this error:

```
(arandr:2458): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 16:52:32.374: gdk_atom_intern: assertion 'atom_name != NULL' failed

(arandr:2458): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 16:52:32.374: gdk_atom_intern: assertion 'atom_name != NULL' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/arandr", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/screenlayout/gui.py", line 344, in main
    app = Application(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/screenlayout/gui.py", line 162, in __init__
    self.filetemplate = self.widget.load_from_x()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/screenlayout/widget.py", line 125, in load_from_x
    self._xrandr.load_from_x()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/screenlayout/xrandr.py", line 155, in load_from_x
    screenline, items = self._load_raw_lines()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/screenlayout/xrandr.py", line 236, in _load_raw_lines
    output = self._output("--verbose")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/screenlayout/xrandr.py", line 75, in _output
    raise Exception("XRandR returned error code %d: %s" %
Exception: XRandR returned error code 1: b'xrandr: output LVDS1 cannot use rotation "normal" reflection "none"\n'
```

Trying to open xrandr always gives me this error:

```
xrandr: output LVDS1 cannot use rotation "normal" reflection "none"
```

I've tried `xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate normal --reflect normal` but again I get the error above.

Answer (score 1):

Asked for help after an hour of searching, found the answer 5 minutes after asking.

Looks like I was missing my xorg.conf file.

```
Xorg :1 -configure
```

generates a new config file at `/root/xorg.conf.new` and copying it to the right place with:

```
cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and everything is back to normal.

Comment: I had the same issue, and this fixed it after a reboot.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I has the same issue, kept getting `xrandr: output eDP1 cannot use rotation "normal" reflection "none"` when running `xrandr -q`.

What worked for me was uninstalling the Intel video drivers (xf86-video-intel) and letting the modesetting drivers take over.

https://man.archlinux.org/man/modesetting.4